# 'dict' object is not callable when creating a dict of degree of a nodes in a conncected graph

Tags: python, dictionary, nodes, networkx, degrees

When I run the code to draw a graph of nodes with highest degree this is the error I get.
the error has been persistent throughout my project wherever I try to use 'dict' it says it is not callable

```
nx.degree(G) 
degrees = dict(nx.degree(G)) #gives error here
nx.set_node_attributes(G, name='degree', values=degrees)
degree_df = pd.DataFrame(G.nodes(data='degree'), columns=['node', 'degree'])
degree_df = degree_df.sort_values(by='degree', ascending=False)
num_nodes_to_inspect = 10
degree_df[:num_nodes_to_inspect].plot(x='node', y='degree', kind='barh').invert_yaxis(
```

output

'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you have before? What is ```nx.degree(G) ``` ? And do you have anything like ```dict = ``` ?

Comment: @fdireito no I have not used dict as a variable anywhere else

Comment: I do not get an error at that line (I've got to do some work like importing networkx and defining `G` before I can run the code you've created).  Can you provide code that we can just copy and paste and run?  The error really seems to suggest that `dict` has been defined to be a dict.

Comment: Unless you are running an ancient Python version, it is possible that you created a variable somewhere named `dict`. It could come from using `import * from ...` from one of your other files. Whenever feasible, try to avoid `import * from ...` and explicitly import the names you really need. Such would also help in quickly understanding where exactly each function comes from. Try `print(dict)` which should give `<class 'dict'>`. You can also try `help(dict)` in an interactive session, which should print out something starting with  `Help on class dict in module builtins:`.